# How to merge multiple excel files and update the merged file's worksheet names as excel files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

Can somebody please help me to resolve this. This is my requirement:

> I have few excel files (It will vary) in a folder D:\Script\Test

The name of the files are ExcelA, ExcelB, ExcelC etc

It has worksheets like this: A1 (for ExcelA), B1(for ExcelB), C1(for ExcelC) etc

> Here I want to merge all those different excel sheets to one excel sheets

> (Lets say the merge file name is 'Final.xlsx')

Condition: Instead of getting the worksheets as its actual names (A1, B1, C1), I want to get it updated with excel file names.

Meaning : Final.xlsx should have merged 3 worksheets with the names: ExcelA, ExcelB, ExcelC

Comment: what you describe is doable _in excel_. you can use macros to load external files - CSV or native excel files - into individual sheets. then summarize/present/process them in another sheet. i don't see any need for PoSh. ///// if you _must_ use powershell, then take a look at the `ImportExcel` module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am just a beginner in scripting. The only thing I do is search things in google and copy paste  and check. If possible then can you please give the script like how to do that ?

Comment: i don't have access to Excel - i use LibreOffice. so i can't show you how to set up the Excel macros to load the external files. nor can  i show you how to use the Powershell ImportExcel module to work with excel. nor can i show you how to use COM objects with powershell. you may want to change your tags to show MSOffice and VBA [VisualBasicForApplications].

Answer (score 0):

1. Run powershell / PowerShell ISE as an administrator
2. Run the following commands,

   - `Install-Module ImportExcel` (and follow the prompts)
   - `Import-Module ImportExcel`
3. Create a script (e.g. MergeExcelWorkbooks.ps1)

   - The below will help you merge 1 sheet each from multiple workbooks and, per requirement, the **merged workbook** (`Final.xlsx`) sheet names are workbook names of the source excel files.

**Script:**

```
$sourceFolderPath = "D:\Script\Test"

$OutputFilePath = "D:\Script\Test\Final.xlsx"

$XLfiles = Get-ChildItem $sourceFolderPath -Filter *.xlsx

foreach ($XLfile in $XLfiles) {

    <# Hints,
    - If there is only 1 sheet or if you want to import data from the 1st sheet (ordinal, i.e index 0) in the Excel file the below would work
    - Else please use the 'WorkSheetName' parameter to specify the sheet name to import from
    - Use the NoHeader switch of Import-Excel if the source Excel sheets do not contain a header; HeaderName parameter can be used in combination with NoHeader to specify a custom header name
    #>
    Import-Excel $XLfile.FullName | Export-Excel $OutputFilePath -WorksheetName $XLfile.BaseName    

}
```

In the above script,

1. `$XLfile.FullName` returns the full filepath of the source `$XLfile`
2. `$XLfile.BaseName` returns the name of the current excel file *(without the extension)*

Please try it out and let me know in the comments if it worked for you *or* if you have a different scenario.

---

**EDIT**
In order to import from a specific sheet use the `-WorkSheetName` parameter of the `Import-Excel` command like below,

```
Import-Excel $XLfile.FullName -WorksheetName 'Snapshots'| Export-Excel $OutputFilePath -WorksheetName $XLfile.BaseName
```

Comment: @Vimal - Can you please let us know the error message? When you post your error message, you can enclose it within the backtick (``) special character so that SO will `highlight` it here

Comment: Thank you Karthick for your script. But I am getting error.
Opened the powershell ISE as an Administrator and ran that install-module:
I clicked Yes to All for the next prompt:

Comment: You can instead post a link to the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: This is the error message I am getting:
https://snipboard.io/nPlJgv.jpg

Comment: Okay, that error didn't happen for me. What version of PowerShell are you using? The variable `$PSVersionTable` can tell you that. Can you try [manual download ImportExcel 7.1.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/7.1.0)? Go to 'Manual Download' under Installation Options. Once downloaded, try to [install the module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-packages/manual-download?view=powershell-7#installing-powershell-modules-from-a-nuget-package).

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.17134.858

Comment: Can you please chat me [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109692/my-se-room1)?

Comment: @Vimal - Just pinged

Comment: Karthick Ganesan, I was able to run that script from another computer. I guess I dont have enough privileges in my offc computer. But I was able to run that script successfully from my personal computer.
Thank you very much for your nice script.
Can you please help me one more thing:
In your script you mentioned it is collecting the data of first work sheet. What I want to collect the data of my 4th worksheet (Its name is snapshots) ?
I tried to modify the script with worksheet but I dont think what I am doing to correct. Can you please help me ?

Comment: Please try the command line I've updated at the end of my post.

Comment: Wonderful!! Thank you very much for your great help. Now I got what I wanted. You are just great!! @Karthick!

Comment: Thanks Vimal! Can you please consider marking this post as "answer" by marking the tick mark beside? This will give some credit points to both you & me and will also help future seekers of a solution to a similar problem.